# Python - Find text using beautifulSoup then replace in original soup variable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
commentary = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'live-text-commentary-wrapper'})
findtoure = commentary.find(text = re.compile('Gnegneri Toure Yaya')).replace('Gnegneri      Toure Yaya', 'Yaya Toure')
```

Commentary contains various instances of Gnegneri Toure Yaya that need changing to Yaya Toure.

`findAll()` doesn't work as findtoure is a list.

The other problem I have is this code simply finds them and replaces them into a new variable called findtoure, I need to replace them in the original soup.

I think I am just looking at this from the wrong perspective.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I hope you had a Beautiful Soup for dinner ;), but I can't blame you if you don't remember.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You cannot do what you want with *just* `.replace()`. From the [BeautifulSoup documentation on `NavigableString`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring):

> You can’t edit a string in place, but you can replace one string with another, using [`replace_with()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with).

That's exactly what you need to do; take each match, then call `.replace()` on the contained text and replace the original with that:

```
findtoure = commentary.find_all(text = re.compile('Gnegneri Toure Yaya'))
for comment in findtoure:
    fixed_text = comment.replace('Gnegneri Toure Yaya', 'Yaya Toure')
    comment.replace_with(fixed_text)
```

If you want to use these comments further, you'll need to do a new find:

```
findtoure = commentary.find_all(text = re.compile('Yaya Toure'))
```

or, if you all you need is the resulting *strings* (so Python `str` objects, not `NavigableString` objects still connected to the `BeautifulSoup` object), just collect the `fixed_text` objects:

```
findtoure = commentary.find_all(text = re.compile('Gnegneri Toure Yaya'))
fixed_comments = []
for comment in findtoure:
    fixed_text = comment.replace('Gnegneri Toure Yaya', 'Yaya Toure')
    comment.replace_with(fixed_text)
    fixed_comments.append(fixed_text)
```

Comment: The unicode statement gives an error. What package is that from ?  does it work in 3.7+ ?

Comment: @blissweb: this was using Python 2 syntax. I've updated it for Python 3.

Comment: how can I print the new text in the loop?