# Deleting a div with a particular class using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I want to delete the specific `div` from `soup` object. 

I am using `python 2.7` and `bs4`.

According to documentation we can use `div.decompose()`.

But that would delete all the `div`. How can I delete a `div` with specific class?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Sure, you can just [`select`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), [`find`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find), or [`find_all`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) the `div`s of interest in the usual way, and then call [`decompose()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) on those divs.

For instance, if you want to remove all divs with class `sidebar`, you could do that with

```
# replace with `soup.findAll` if you are using BeautifulSoup3
for div in soup.find_all("div", {'class':'sidebar'}): 
    div.decompose()
```

If you want to remove a div with a specific `id`, say `main-content`, you can do that with

```
soup.find('div', id="main-content").decompose()
```

Comment: Short and precise. Thanks!

Comment: @lemonhead Do you by any chance know how to put a replacement text at the decomposed location?

Comment: @CodeGuru in that case you wouldn't decompose, you would select/find the element and then call [`elem.string.replace_with`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with). 
 See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056633/python-find-text-using-beautifulsoup-then-replace-in-original-soup-variable)

Comment: d=div.extract() if you want to get the removed element as d, and do something further.

Answer (score 14):

This will help you:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

markup = '<a>This is not div <div class="1">This is div 1</div><div class="2">This is div 2</div></a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup,"html.parser")
a_tag = soup

soup.find('div',class_='2').decompose()

print a_tag
```

Output:

```
<a>This is not div <div class="1">This is div 1</div></a>
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: How is it going to work? You assigned a value to `a_tag` and then modified `soup` but printing `a_tag`.? I could not get it working.

Answer (score 12):

Hope it help:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag

markup = '<a>This is not div <div class="1">This is div 1</div><div class="2">This is div 2</div></a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup,"html.parser")

for tag in soup.select('div.1'):
  tag.decompose()

print(soup)
```

Comment: Works like charm in BS4.

Answer (score -1):

```
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    >>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<body><div>1</div><div class="comment"><strong>2</strong></div></body>')
    >>> for div in soup.findAll('div', 'comment'):
    ...   div.extract()
    ... 
    <div class="comment"><strong>2</strong></div>
    >>> soup
    <body><div>1</div></body>
```

Comment: extract function doesnt remove the div from original soup.