# Python: Deleting all divs without class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to delete all divs without classes (but not the content that is in the div).

**My input**

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="test">
            <p>abc</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The output I want**

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<div class="test">    
    <p>abc</p>
</div>
```

**My try 1**

Based on "[Deleting a div with a particular class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32064299/7082264)":

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<h1>Test</h1><div><div><div class="test"><p>abc</p></div></div></div>', 'html.parser')   
for div in soup.find_all("div", {'class':''}): 
    div.decompose()
print(soup)
# <h1>Test</h1>
```

**My try 2**

```
from htmllaundry import sanitize
myinput = '<h1>Test</h1><div><div><div class="test"><p>abc</p></div></div></div>'
myoutput = sanitize(myinput)
print myoutput
# <p>Test</p><p>abc</p> instead of <h1>Test</h1><div class="test"><p>abc</p></div>
```

**My try 3**

Based on "[Clean up HTML in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46371211/7082264)"

```
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner

def sanitize(dirty_html):
    cleaner = Cleaner(remove_tags=('font', 'div'))

    return cleaner.clean_html(dirty_html)


myhtml = '<h1>Test</h1><div><div><div class="test"><p>abc</p></div></div></div>'

print(sanitize(myhtml))
# <div><h1>Test</h1><p>abc</p></div>
```

**My try 4**

```
from html_sanitizer import Sanitizer
sanitizer = Sanitizer()  # default configuration
output = sanitizer.sanitize('<h1>Test</h1><div><div><div class="test"><p>abc</p></div></div></div>')
print(output)
# <h1>Test</h1><p>abc</p>
```

Problem: A `div` element is used to wrap the HTML fragment for the parser, therefore `div` tags are not allowed. (Source: [Manual](https://pypi.org/project/html-sanitizer/))

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude div without class, preserving its content:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
markup = '<h1>Test</h1><div><div><div class="test"><p>abc</p></div></div></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup,"html.parser")
for tag in soup.find_all():
    empty = tag.name == 'div' and not(tag.has_attr('class'))
    if not(empty):
        print(tag)
```

Output:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<div class="test"><p>abc</p></div>
<p>abc</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data="""
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="test">
            <p>abc</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features="html5lib")

for div in soup.find_all("div", class_=True):
    print(div)
```

Comment: The output of your script is "abc abc" and not "<p>abc</p>" as requested.