# How to remove element "<div> <div style" from the soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a html in which I want to remove element `<div> <div style`. I tried below code, but to no avail

```
for d in soup.select('div > div.style'):
    d.extract()
```

Could you please elaborate on how to do so?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

texte = """
<div class="content mw-parser-output" id="bodyContent">
    <div>
        <div style="clear:both; background-image:linear-gradient(180deg, #E8E8E8, white); border-top: dashed 2px #AAAAAA; padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em; margin-top: 1em; direction: ltr;">
        This article is issued from <a class="external text" href="https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/?title=Love&amp;oldid=60218267" title="Last edited on 2020-09-02">Wiktionary</a>. The text is licensed under <a class="external text" href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/">Creative Commons - Attribution - Sharealike</a>. Additional terms may apply for the media files.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(texte, 'html.parser')

for d in soup.select('div > div.style'):
    d.extract()
    
print(soup.prettify())
```

My expected result is

```
<div class="content mw-parser-output" id="bodyContent">
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to extract only text ??

Comment: you want to remove "div" element or "div" with style attribute?

Comment: @qaiser I've added the expected output. Please see my update.

Comment: @KokoJumbo I've added the expected output. Please see my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(texte, 'html.parser')
soup.select_one('div > div#content').parent.extract()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: I want to impose a stricter condition, i.e., such `<div> <div style` is the (not necessarily direct) children of an element `<div class="mw-body" id="content">`. Can you modify your code to account for this?

Comment: @LEAnhDung - take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

texte = """
<div class="content mw-parser-output" id="bodyContent">
    <div>
       <div style="clear:both; background-image:linear-gradient(180deg, #E8E8E8, white); border-top:
 dashed 2px #AAAAAA; padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em; margin-top: 1em; direction: ltr;">
       This article is issued from <a class="external text" href="https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/?ti
tle=Love&amp;oldid=60218267" title="Last edited on 2020-09-02">Wiktionary</a>. The text is licensed u
nder <a class="external text" href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/">Creative Commons
 - Attribution - Sharealike</a>. Additional terms may apply for the media files.
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(texte, 'html.parser')

for d in soup.find_all('div', {"style": True}):
    d.find_parent("div").extract()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with decompose method, [Deleting a div with a particlular class using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063985/deleting-a-div-with-a-particlular-class-using-beautifulsoup)

```
for div in soup.findAll("div", {'style':'clear:both; background-image:linear-gradient(180deg, #E8E8E8, white); border-top: dashed 2px #AAAAAA; padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em; margin-top: 1em; direction: ltr;'}):
   div.decompose()

print(soup)
 <div class="content mw-parser-output" id="bodyContent">

</div>
```